# How to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in each api request - Ionic Capacitor App

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have migrated my old ionic angular Cordova app to the ionic angular capacitor and after all, the code migrated my app is showing the below issue. I know this is a very common issue. In my old app, there is some setting available for this in the config.xml file.

Question: How can I add a similar configuration in the ionic capacitor app?

[image]

**CONFIG.XML**

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

**ERROR**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://service-internal.company.com/service.svc/Authenticate'
> from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

**New App Details**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.8 (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.6.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 15.2.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 15.2.2
   @angular/cli                  : 15.2.2
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 8.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 4.7.0
   @capacitor/android : 4.7.0
   @capacitor/core    : 4.7.0
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : 1.7.2

System:

   NodeJS : v16.15.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 8.19.2
   OS     : macOS Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these plugins:

https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http or https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/http

Comment: Thanks for your answer @StackoverBlows! As I mentioned, I have migrated this app, so if I change any package, I have to make changes in many places. Currently i am using this package import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Then you would need to edit the server to allow cors. There's nothing else you can do. More info can be found here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors